# Can you 100% complete Dark Souls 3 using only melee weapon?

Tags: dark-souls-3

As far as I remember, one can 100% complete dark souls 1 using only melee weapon, that means to **reach and kill every boss and find every item** without using spells, bows, throwing knives and stuff like it.

**Is the same true for Dark Souls 3?**

I'm asking because I am facing the tree in Undead Setlement, which has a treasure hanging on its branches, that treasure looks unreachable without range. **Please don't spoil** that specific case, I just want to know the general answer to the question whether I can constrain myself by "melee only weapons".

Comment: throw your sword :v

Comment: what does "100%" complete mean?  It's obviously not just "finish the game".  Get every pick-up-able item in the entire world?  Because that itself can't even be done until 3 playthroughs

Comment: there are some melee weapons which have weapon art or special strong attack which - no spoilers here - have somehow extended range. Are you ok with using these?

Comment: @Kritner, I am not sure what you are asking. There is very clear and even highlighted definition in my question. Yes, I want to pick up every item, and no, I don't care about anything but need to use ranged attack, so I don't care about numbers of playthroughs.

Comment: @arghtype, I would say no, since effectively this would be ranged weapon. I need to know whether I need to use range or just think and explore. But, I guess, PapaStan have already answered to this quesiton.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

For example, the [Red and White Shield](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Red+and+White+Shield) is only reachable with ranged weapon.